# Flip vertical UIWebview to be shown when view did load

Tags: objective-c, ios

I was searching information to show a uiwebview using a flip horizontal effect like modal transition one in viewDidLoad event, but I wasn't successful, even in apple documents. Can anybody help me with that?

Many thanks

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to animate on viewDidLoad. That's not the place. You have to animate when you add the view to your view hierarchy, as stated by @Safecase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the transition to animate webView with the view add your webView like this.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:poster.view duration:3
               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{
                   [self.view addSubview:yourWebView];
               }
            completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

The animation you want to add can be done on the UIView. So you should addSubView the UIWebview to the UIView and then do the animation on the UIView.